# PNG inside SVG - not working in Firefox

Tags: svg, base64, png

I am trying to place a PNG image directly into the SVG file (using Base64). Here is a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/bL11Lp8d/

```
<use href="#img1" transform="matrix(20,10,-5,20,50,50)" />
```

It works fine in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox. Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has no width and height attributes. Firefox still requires them.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500">
  <defs>
    <image  id="img1"  href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="  width="5" height="5" />
  </defs>
  <use href="#img1" transform="matrix(20,10,-5,20,50,50)" />
</svg>
```

SVG 1.1 says they are mandatory, The SVG 2 specification says optional.